# Creating an element using .map function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling while creating an element that is passed by the `.map` function. Basically, I want my webpage to create a div element with some date in it when a button is clicked for that I'm using a `.map` function but it isn't working out.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = {title:`${title}`, desc:`${desc}`, date:`${date}`};
        data.map(userinfo =>{
            return(<div>
                <h1>{userinfo.title}</h1>
            </div>)
        })
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Comment: [mcve] -> _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: before anyone answers your problem: _never use `.map` without adding key attributes to your returned elements_. React is [pretty clear about this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). And [never use the array index as key](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: If you're not using the return value of `.map()`, then `.map()` is not the right tool.

Comment: `array#map` works with array, you have an object. You have to convert your object into array.

Comment: Like what @Andreas said, be more specific about your question. Do you need help using `Array.prototype.map()`? If so, make a simpler example and search on google and stack overflow for existing answers.

Comment: The function is totally wrong . From where `title , desc , date ` coming

Answer (score 0):

In reactJS, if we want to display our data in HTML webpage we usually do that in the render funciton.

We can use userInfo variable in the state object.
The userInfo data is hardcoded for demonstration purposes but you can also populate the userInfo variable either using API or in any other way you like.

Moreover, showUserInfo is another variable (initially false) that would render the data once it is set to true

```
this.state = {
  userInfo: [
      {
          title: 'one',
          desc: '',
          date: new Date()
      },
      {
          title: 'two',
          desc: '',
          date: new Date()
       }
   ],
   showUserInfo: false
}
```

On a click event we can set showUserInfo to true using setState function.

more on setState function via this link  ->
https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState( 
      {
        ...this.state,
        showUserInfo: true
      } 
    )
}
```

In the render function, if showUserInfo is false then userInfo.map is never going to render unless showUserInfo is set to true which we do using a click listener that is associated with our function handleSubmit.

```
render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Click Me</button>

        { this.state.showUserInfo && 
        this.state.userInfo.map(item =>(
          <div>
            <p> {item.date.toString()}  </p>
          </div>
        ) )  }

      </div>
    ); 
  }
```

Overall the result looks a something like this.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.state = {
      showUserInfo: false,
      userInfo: [
        {
          title: 'one',
          desc: '',
          date: new Date()
        },
        {
          title: 'two',
          desc: '',
          date: new Date()
        }
      ],
    }

  }

  handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState( 
      {
        ...this.state,
        showUserInfo: true
      } 
    )
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Click Me</button>

        { this.state.showUserInfo && 
        this.state.userInfo.map(item =>(
          <div>
            <p> {item.date.toString()}  </p>
          </div>
        ) )  }
      </div>
    ); 
  }

}
```